# For loop keeps breaking out after 1 instance - Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have looked everywhere I can think of for anything that can provide an answer to this. First time posting a question here - I can usually find my answers. I have a for loop that is pulling information from a range of data that is formatted in one cell like this: 09/01/2016 - Status changed to active.

The loop is supposed to first see how many values are in that column then go one by one and split the data into a simple array, post it into two columns on a separate sheet, then move onto the next one. The problem is that it stops after the first entry.

```
var numEntries = dataSheet.getRange(1,i+1,1000).getValues();
var lastEntry = numEntries.filter(String).length;
if (lastEntry == 7) {
  // no change data to date
  sheet.getRange(18,3).setValue("No changes yet");
  } else {
var changeData = dataSheet.getRange(8,i+1,lastEntry-7).getValues();
for (var y = 0; y < changeData.length; y++) {
    var changeHistory = changeData[y][y].split(" - ");
    sheet.getRange(nextRow+1,2).setValue(changeHistory[0]);
    sheet.getRange(nextRow+1,3).setValue(changeHistory[1]);
    nextRow++;
  Logger.log(nextRow);
  Logger.log(changeData.length);
  Logger.log(y);
  }
}
```

I know that it is executing properly because it is properly setting the "No changes yet" value when there are no entries. Variable nextRow starts at a value of 17, and the log properly shows changeData.length with the number of entries and y being equal to 0. But then it stops. It doesn't follow the loop that y is still less than changeData.length. Any help is very much appreciated!

[edit] - I also want to point out that it does properly split and populate the first value into the two cells I want it to, so the whole for statement does work, it just doesn't loop. [edit]

> [16-09-29 15:37:48:514 CDT] 18.0
>  [16-09-29 15:37:48:515 CDT]
>   11.0
>  [16-09-29 15:37:48:515 CDT] 0.0

Comment: Your code is not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`changeData` is an `n*1` Array.
You are increasing `y` and and you are also trying to get the `y`-th column from `changeData`.
After the first iteration this is `undefined` because there's only one column.
`undefined` does not have a `split` method throwing an exception and terminating the script. (You may not see this exception, these kinds of exceptions aren't always shown to the user for some reason)

Try

```
var changeHistory = changeData[y][0].split(" - ");
```

instead.

Comment: I wasn't seeing the exception, but once you put it out there, it made perfect sense! This worked! Huge thank you!